# Building agents with GuiAgent class

Tags: java, user-interface, pug, artificial-intelligence, agent

I want to create Multi Agent application with GUI and I supposed to use GuiAgent class, but I didn't find any documentation to start developing it, my application consist to create a chat room between two agents and communicate by using the interface, so plz help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an example in this link:
http://jade.tilab.com/documentation/chat-demo/

If you want more information about JADE, there is a good book which covers differents topics of it:
https://www.mit.bme.hu/system/files/oktatas/targyak/8671/Developing-Multi-Agent-Systems-with-JADE.pdf

Comment: for the chat-demo it's for android and it's more complicated , for the book i saw it , and it's helpless :/